# Ki Technique - Long Distance Attack + Projection

Tags: anima-beyond-fantasy

First off, want to thank everyone for their answers to me so far - you've all been really helpful and fast, and it's great for a new GM to this system :)

This question is about the Ki Power Long Distance Attack. It states that you can add range to your attack, and then for base damage you :

---

> "To Determine a Technique's long distance base damage, the player
> chooses either the damage produced by the hand held weapon, or a value
> equivalent to twice the user's base presence, plus his power bonus
> (nevertheless the attack will not observe any of the special rules of
> the grasped weapon)."

---

This brings up several questions :

1. If the user is making a presence attack, what damage type is used? Is it unarmed? Is it the type of the held weapon? Is it energy?
2. If the user uses his weapon's base damage, is strength included? (since power is included in the presence version).
3. If the user uses his weapon's base damage, are secondary effects applied, such as say electric damage if you are air attuned and take that power? It says that rules for the weapon aren't applied but I'm assuming that means like, tripping people or w/e you just get a normal attack...
4. If the user takes the projection power, and teleports behind the person to make the attack - is it STILL a projectile? If he uses presence, does he actually attack with the weapon? If so, does he use the weapon's damage type with 2x his presence as base damage? This wording though O_o.

My initial read is this -

If you use a weapon, its weapon BD + str bonus and you apply all effects of the weapon as if it had hit you in melee.

If you use presence, it's 2x presence + pow bonus and you treat it like unarmed or Energy DT (I can't decide which)

If you use presence and TP...I'm lost.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's try to answer these:

1. If he is using his Presence to attack, the damage is double Presence plus his power bonus. You can choose, when you create the technique you decide if you want to use your Presence  or your weapon (be this an actual weapon, a natural weapon or your fists).
2. I actually don't know, and I don't believe there is anywhere that explicitly states this, but my guess is yes. Since you are "attacking" with your weapon and there is an exception to specifically special weapon abilities (this rule about special weapon abilities is always, whatever you chose damage from weapon or Presence)
3. Again, I don't think you are going to find anything specific in the book, the best I can do is if the power increases the base damage of the weapon, then yes, it applies. Like other static Ki abilities.
4. Yes, the attack states it is a projectile, always. You throw something (whatever visual effect the creator of the technique wants) and then you move after it. You let yourself be moved through the torrent of energy blahblahblah, whatever fluff is it. If you attack with Presence, usually no, you don't attack with your weapon (I guess the creator of the technique can say that we wants to look like it, but you really don't, you attack with your inner energy). And no, you choose which one, you cannot get both. You could do multiple attacks and do the technique to cover the distance and then use a normal attack.

I got caught up also in this, because when you usually do damage like double presence plus power bonus, it usually is an energy attack and damages in energy armor, but with techniques, there is a special power for that. And I asked around some friends and even though I could not find anything in the book (I haven't look that much, mind you), they all agreed that it will count as an unarmed attack for armor purposes (so, not energy unless you also buy that with the technique and you could touch energy if your character can already do that, like with static ki abilities)

So, recap:

- If you use a weapon, it's weapon BD + str bonus and you attack on whatever armor your weapon attacks. If you do not use a weapon, you do Presencex2 + power bonus and attack on your unarmed armor type (I don't know the names of armor types in English, but I guess something like blunt?). Neither use special weapon abilities (the weapon ones, all other ones, you can use).
- If you also TP, it just means that at the end of the attack, you have moved near your opponent, it does not change damage or the armor type that you are hitting in.

Hope this helps!